# Computer Vision System (vision video player) & GUI

Tags: matlab-cvst

I want to know how can I do for integrating `vision.VideoPlayer` into a GUI Axes please, i'm using computer vision system i tried to integrate this tools into axis but i don't arrive, the size of real time video image is 640x480 RGB

```
videocam1 = vision.VideoPlayer;
 videocam2 = vision.VideoPlayer;
 while get(hObject,'Value')  


    frame1 = getdata(cam1,1,'uint8');
    frame1 = double(frame1) ;

    frame2 = getdata(cam2,1,'uint8');
    frame2 = double(frame2);


    m1 = min(min(min(frame1))) ; M1 = max(max(max(frame1))) ;
    m2 = min(min(min(frame2))) ; M2 = max(max(max(frame2))) ;

    frame01 = (frame1-m1)/(M1-m1) ;
    frame02 = (frame2-m2)/(M2-m2) ;

%     showFrameOnAxis(hAxes.axis1, videocam1.step(frame01));
%     showFrameOnAxis(hAxes.axis2, videocam2.step(frame02));

    videocam1.step(frame01);
    videocam2.step(frame02);

    nframe = nframe+1 ;

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example called [Video Display in a Custom User Interface](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/video-display-in-a-custom-user-interface.html) that shows you how to do just that.